# Trying to use account.balance in an if statement

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, coinbase-api

I am messing around with Coinbase's API using Python. I am **trying** to write some code that pulls the account balance from my wallet, then makes an if statement (e.g if account balance < (number) do something). The problem is that I keep getting an error. I'll elaborate, below is a sample of the code:

```
balance = account.balance
if balance < 8000:
  print("Bambi")
```

I get the error "TypeError: 'Money' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

To be clear, when I simply run:

```
print(account.balance)
```

I get BTC = #.#######

I guess my question is, how can I change the account.balance to an integer so that I can run while/if statements with that number?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `balance.amount`:

```
amount = float(account.balance.amount)
if amount < 8000.0:
    print("Bambi")
```

Comment: Thanks, I just ran it and got "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: just ran that and got "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#.########'"

Comment: Weird, this time I got "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: @Jay Are you sure you are converting to `float` as per my code example ?

Comment: nevermind I accidently put if balance.amount instead of just amount. Thanks a lot for your time and help man!